# Standard way to tension a string using a motor?

Tags: microcontroller, motor, mechanical, system, mechanical-assembly

I am dealing with a design that requires me to tension a small string, about 5 inches long with a diameter of about 1-2 mm, and then keep it under tension (lock it in place) without the use of additional power. Is there any standard way to tension a string such as this using a motor or electronic components, or does anyone know if components exist that are available for preview from manufacturers that will do this?

Let me quickly clarify the tensioning requirements here with a visual aid. I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

I need to program a microcontroller to activate/deactivate the black body in the image. When activated, it should tension the string up to a maximum amount of tension and then lock it in place after some period of time while supplying power to it. When it is activated again (while it is in the locked state), it should unlock the string. Is this possible, and how? Thanks in advance for any help! It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Use a motor driving a [worm-gear reduction](http://precisionparts.wmberg.com/ecatalog/gearBoxes/en) with the string locked to the output shaft.

In order to tension the string, turn the motor ON in the proper direction until the required tension is achieved, then turn the motor OFF. The worm gear will then keep the string under tension with no power applied to the motor.  In order to release the tension, turn the motor ON again, for a while,  but in the opposite direction.

Comment: Yes, if holding with power off is desired.  Through a screw and nut would be an easier sourced form of this idea.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: There are [lots of ways](https://www.google.com/search?q=linear+motor&espv=2&biw=1137&bih=783&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=NoisVM_NDISVyQS_-YDQCQ&ved=0CEEQ7Ak&dpr=0.9) to do it. Ya pays yer money and ya makes yer choice...

Comment: @ChrisStratton Chris, screw and a nut would be perfect for this application. Expanding on this idea, in fact, do you or anyone else have any clues as to where I may find a threaded, flexible plastic rod (1-2mm in diameter) that can actually take the place of the string?

Comment: @Alexandru - by the nature of the materials, flexible plastic usually doesn't wear well, so nobody makes such threaded rod. Furthermore, 1-2 mm is (by screw standards) extremely small.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast You are so right, it does not exist. Perhaps not plastic then? The material is irrelevant to me so long as it doesn't snap easily and can be tensioned. The maximum I can go is 1/8 inch diameter, but its really hard to find something like this, like you said. However, there must be something out there that someone makes that might be a fit for this idea. If anyone happens to know of a manufacturer for such a part, online or from some sort of hobby stores, please let me know! Thanks for all of your feedback so far, everyone!

Comment: Go to a radio control hobby shop and ask for a semi-rigid plastic pushrod with a threaded metal end in the style of a Sullivan Goldenrod.  Or go to a hardware store and get a small turnbuckle or eyebolt and some picture frame wire.

Comment: @ChrisStratton An eyebolt and a snake chain would be PERFECT.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the simplest way to do this would be use a solenoid. When powered, it will pull the string taut, and when depowered it can go loose again. Putting a tension spring between the solenoid and the string will allow you to set the tension.

Something like this might work:

http://au.element14.com/multicomp/mcsmo-1253l24std/solenoid-open-frame-pull-24v/dp/2008794

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, there may be several ways to do this:

1. Spring tensioner + powered release.

   - Similar to air-reduction brakes, where the typically imagined function is done by a spring, which must be actively opposed when its full function (wheels skidding on dry pavement when fully loaded) is not wanted.
2. Same as #1, but with a weight instead of a spring.

   - Offers a different relationship between force and displacement than a spring.
3. Powered tensioner + brake.

   - The brake operates like #1: applied by a spring, must be actively released.

This list is by no means exhaustive, but it might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

When you said latch in place, I immediately thought [Ratchet and Pawl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratchet_%28device%29).